# Funil de conversão Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics-api

Olá, tenho uma página de compra que quando o usuário decide fazer a compra, é redirecionado para a página do paypal. Pelo funil de conversão eu consigo ver se o usuário voltou para minha página a partir do paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, mas primeiro você precisa definir essa 'página de volta' como um Goal. Se o paypal mandar o usuário de volta pra essa página e esse processo de ir e voltar durar menos que 30 minutos, vai ser capturado normalmente e aparecerá no funil, pois a sessão não terá expirado.